# Right way to store persistent but volatile app data in Mac os

Tags: macos

I need to store some data of my app and I'm trying to figure out where should I place it. I need to save the user-related statistic database which is growing during the user PC activity. I also need to store log file which I don't want to be deleted during the restart. So I don't consider it temporary but persistent instead.
I've read the [article](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFileSystem/Articles/WhereToPutFiles.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001411-BAJHCHJI) but it confused me still more. I didn't find the right way to store my data. The only directory I find to be the right way is "Application support" but Apple [states](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFileSystem/Articles/LibraryDirectory.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002282-BAJHCHJI) unambiguously *"This directory should never contain any kind of user data."*

So is there a way to store the data without guide violation?
I just don't want to reinvent the wheel and store my data in an inappropriate place so the end-user would curse me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

General data should be in `~/Library/application-name`, and logs in `~/Library/Logs`.

Comment: geekosaur, thank you! I was confused a bit by Opera\Firefox ways to store data. But it seems you are right so long as the Apple default soft stores its data right in the ~/Library.

Comment: Opera and Firefox (and Calibre and some other programs that are more geared toward portability) generally do things that are easier to make portable between platforms.  Using them as examples is probably a bad idea unless you plan to port your program to Windows and Linux — and even then, people will appreciate it if you take the time to follow native standards on each platform.  (The programs I mentioned are large and complex enough that it's understandable they don't want to have to rearrange all their state and user data storage on different platforms.)

Comment: My program is cross-platform too and I see no difficulties to place app data to the location the users used to. The main difficulty is to find this right way :)

Comment: I don't think ~/Library/$APPNAME is correct actually. I see this is an old answer so maybe things have changed, but it looks like ~/Library/Application Support/$APPIDENTIFIER or ~/Libary/Caches/$APPIDENTIFIER are better places.